Is there a way to disable screenshot assertions in playwright?
I am introducing screenshot testing to a project I am working on. Due to differences on screenshots generated locally (macOS) and on the CI (Linux) I decided to generate screenshots via a Github Action triggered by a comment on a PR. The issue with this approach is that running the tests locally fails due to not matching screenshots. To avoid this situation I would like to ignore calls to toHaveScreenshot to be ignored locally.
I tried to set maxDiffPixelRatio to 1 but this didn't work... Is there any other way to achieve this behavior? For instance, customizing the behavior of toHaveScreenshot? 

I don't see why there should be any difference running in CI and locally. Are you running both in the same image, and using the same headless setting? Simply throwing out screenshot tests locally seems like treating dandruff with decapitation, but if you must do this, maybe something iike test.skip(!process.env.CI), or use filtering again using the process.env.CI flag to determine if you're in CI or not.

@ggorlen from what I understood so far there are many reasons for these differences and the time invested in figuring it out is starting to defeat the purpose of screenshot snapshots. I already tried to use macOS images on the CI so that it's the same as locally but this resulted in very long test runs on the CI and the screenshots still had differences (this is also expensive). I also tried tweaking the CSS font properties but it didn't help either when using Linux or macOS images on the CI. I didn't try to change my laptop settings because there's a lot of people working on these repos.

OK, how about a docker container?

I also tried that locally but the effort didn't seem worth it given that the same can be done on the CI. At least on the CI we have all the token and env vars needed. Locally, we would need to create a lot of new stuff to inject that into the container and everyone would need to get used to run the tests on the container instead of locally. It took me more than a day to figure this out so I decided to try the CI which I managed to get working faster.

In any case, if you have any hints on how to setup a docker container to run locally I'm all ears. For it to be workable I need to:

Get the local ´.npmrc´ into the container so that it can read from our private npm registry.
Cache dependencies so that we don't need to wait for yarn install every single time.
Cache the build for similar reasons.
Extract the screenshots to the host so they can be commited or commit them from the container which would also require git access.


https://playwright.dev/docs/docker

I am aware of the page you shared but it only shows how to startup the container. There's a lot more that needs to happen for the tests to run inside a container. What about injecting tokens, installing deps, building the app, running the tests, and extracting the screenshots? Do you have an example?
So far this approach looked more appropriate for small scale and open source projects and not really for large scale and private projects. Unless I'm a total docker noob and I'm missing something.

I forgot to add that we are running the tests against a local build and not against a live environment. The examples I see on the page you shared are for running against a live environment. On top of that I still don't get how to extract the screenshots from the container

I can't give a full Docker tutorial, but this should solve your complaints about different systems causing variants in screenshots. If you have a large scale project, I'm surprised it's not already using Docker. Seems like you'd have more compatibility problems with 20 people working in random, undockerized environments than just screenshot tests. I'm not sure what the difference is between a "local build" and a "live environment". Playwright just visits a URL and automates it--doesn't matter how that page came to be, it's hosted on a server somewhere. Local or otherwise is irrelevant.

To ignore screenshots locally, you could add a script to package.json, something like:
"scripts": {
    "e2e-local": "npx playwright test --ignore-snapshots"
}

Then run that in the terminal: npm run e2e-local or just run the command directly.
However, a problem I ran into when generating base screenshots locally causing issues on CI, was simply because my monitor was at 125% scale instead of 100%.  When I changed it to 100% and regenerated the base screenshots, they worked on CI.  Maybe that is worth checking out.

´--ignore-snapshots´ seems to be exactly what I needed. A pitty this didn't show up when I searched about ignoring screenshots

I checked the scale of my screen but it is set to default. In any case, there's around 20 people working on this repo on a daily basis so asking them to change their display settings to run tests wouldn't be feasible imo.
